# How to identify the first child of the table element using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to retrieve the first element of the table element using css.

below is the html code,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>first</tr> //want to access this
            <tr>second</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

i tried this and works

```
div.wrapper table tbody tr:nth-of-type(1)
```

Wanted to know if there is some neater way to access it.

Comment: define `first element` you can do just `table tr:nth-of-type(1)`  if you want to get the first row. Technically the first element would be `table > *:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: Do u want to select first element of each div?

Comment: i want to get first row within table

Comment: or `table tr:ntn-of-type(1)` or `table tr:nth-child(1)` or `table tr:first-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>first</tr> //want to access this
            <tr>second</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can use a CSS selector like this to refer to it:

```
div.wrapper > table > tbody > tr:first-of-type
```

You could also use any of these too:

```
div.wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1)
div.wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)
div.wrapper > table > tbody > tr:first-child
```